# Undefined Method in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
class User
    has_one :user_profile
end
class UserProfile
    belongs_to :user
end
```

I am rendering a form for editing the user's account:

```
<%= form_for current_user do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field current_user.user_profile.first_name %>
<%= end %>
```

But that throws an error:

```
NoMethodError in Account#edit
undefined method `Andy' for #<User:0x5f375e8>
```

Why is the value of the `first_name` being used?

How do I fix this (without using a partial) ?

Also, if someone could guide me to either a book or some comprehensive online tutorials for using forms (and nested forms) in Rails, *I would highly appreciate it*. Forms are driving me nuts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to the text_field helper is a symbol naming the model object's attribute. So in your case it should be:

```
<%= form_for current_user.user_profile do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
<% end %>
```

If your form needs to edit both the User and UserProfile model objects, you'll need fields_for to switch context.

```
<%= form_for current_user do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :some_user_attribute %>
  <%= f.fields_for current_user.user_profile do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for

Comment: It seems that the `first_name` is in the `user_profile` object, which belongs to the user object. So what he need should be `f.fields_to` for creating a form with nested models.

Comment: Oops, thanks @PeterWong I forgot that part. Silly noodl.. Answer updated.